# Exclude values from mean in excel PivotTable

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to calculate the average salary in a PivotTable, but i only want to include the people that have a salary, so that those with the value 0 is excluded.

My data is already grouped, and a simplified example looks like this:

| Group | Total Salary | Number of People |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alfa | 34417383 | 1001 |
| Bravo | 87587880 | 550 |
| Charlie | 0 | 1485 |

So what i want in my pivot table looks like this

| Group | Mean Salary |
| --- | --- |
| Alfa | 34 383 |
| Bravo | 157 816 |
| Charlie | 0 |
| **Total** | **78 410** |

But instead all the people in Charlie have been included so it looks like this instead

| Group | Mean Salary |
| --- | --- |
| Alfa | 34 383 |
| Bravo | 157 816 |
| Charlie | 0 |
| **Total** | **40 120** |

---

I have tried different stuff relating to the field i created called Mean Salary.

(my excel is Norwegian so sorry if i translate the functions wrong)

`SUM('Total Salary') / IF('Total Salary'<>0; 'Number of People'; 1)`

I have tried many variations of this, but it seems like that approach doesn't work when dealing with a Total-field in a Pivot table.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise it is likely that your question is closed due to lack of peliminary work by you.

Comment: The result cannot be changed in PivotTable, you can try the Power Query.

Comment: Ahhh thank you @Lee! That works

Comment: @weeiieew ,,, seems you are struggling with zeros to HIDE,,,, On "Row Labels" column has a Filter Button, hit & Deselect "0" from the filter list. For the CALCULATED FIELD,,,, you need to modify the formula should like,,, `if(SUM('Total Salary') / IF('Total Salary'<>0; 'Number of People'; 1)=0,"",SUM('Total Salary') / IF('Total Salary'<>0; 'Number of People'; 1))` ☺